# Levi-Civita and Kronecker delta notation

Tags: calculus, kronecker-delta

I was wondering how to do the following

$\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_{jk}=\epsilon_{iji}=0$

I get this is $0$ but don't understand how they got the $\epsilon_{iji}$

Comment: To get more than one character in subscript in Mathmode, surround all of the things you want to be in subscript with {}. e.g. $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is written \epsilon_{ijk}. I've made these edits in your question.

Comment: What is the $\sigma_{Jk}$ here ?

Answer (score 0):

We have $\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{jk}=\epsilon_{ijj}=\epsilon_{jij}$, where the second $=$ uses cyclic invariance. The statements $\epsilon_{iji}=0,\,\epsilon_{jij}=0$ are really the same statement twice, differently indexed. Any source that wrote $\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{jk}=\epsilon_{iji}$ has effected an $i\leftrightarrow j$ relabelling, which shouldn't have been done, not least because it changes which index isn't contracted.